# Is there a better way to return an object if it exists in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that searches for images in different ways, one by one, and for each trial, if it finds one, the function returns that image.

The code becomes quite clunky if I search for various images, is there a more elegant way of trying to find an object and returning it if it exists?

```
var image = $('a.jqzoom')[0].getAttribute('href');
if (image)
    return image;
```

Then, I keep trying other ways to find images one after the other, for example:

```
var image = $('a.asdf')[0].getAttribute('href');
if (image)
    return image;
```

Comment: Make it a function...?

Comment: Return is only valid inside a function so already be a function

Comment: @Svend yes it's already a function. I suppose I could make the tags an array and loop through them one by one with a for loop. I was more wondering if there is a better way to write `if (x) return x;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zpuynvuu/1/

Comment: You are probably looking for syntax like "return value1 || value2 || value3;", which will take first, non-undefined value from value1,value2,value3, etc.

Comment: It looks to me like it's code duplicated throughout several functions. Make the duplicated code a function and call it from the other functions. (If that's not what this question is about then I must've misunderstood.)

Comment: @jevgenig ah that works great, thank you! Didn't realize I could simply string these along with `||` operator after return, thought that perhaps using the return statement like that I would have to keep everything on one line, but this allows me to write each line with just a `||` after it, much simpler.

Comment: @YPCrumble, Great. You can accept RobG's answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
return $('a.jqzoom')[0].href || <value if not found>;
```

so if no element is found, the first part returns *undefined* and the second value is returned. A more jQuery-ish way is:

```
return $('a.jqzoom').prop('href') || <value if not found>;
```

But I'm a bit puzzled, isn't the href of an A element supposed to be a document (or some other text based object), not an image?

Comment: It's a custom scraper for sites that have odd layouts - this one uses javascript to pull the image urls which is why I'm pulling from the a element. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If your function doesn't end with the `return` statement it has the return value `undefined`. So you should just write:

```
return $('a.asdf')[0].getAttribute('href');
```

It's basically equivalent to what you already got (it's a little looser, by virtue of the truthy check you got.